# Digital Signage Websocket Control

Tags: html, digital

I am trying to figure out a way of having a customer walk up to a screen scan a QR code and then have control of the content on the screen via their web browser. I know bright sign can do this but unfortunately i need it within our SCALA players.

also dont want it to join a local hotspot like this video but more to use 4g and control a webpage anyone done this sort of thing.

Maybe using websockets or similar?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDni5mgMUPM

Comment: Rather than snippets of code, can you provide a [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example please?

Comment: i used websockets to control desktop browser application (desktop PWA) using mobile browser application ( webView app). except fullscreen rest i could control like play, pause, seek, mute etc using Web APIs